# Execute command of bitcoin app on ubuntu from php - no result

Tags: php, shell-exec

I need to execute command to generate new address from bitcoin node that is installed on my machine with ubuntu OS. This command have to be called from php and result need to be displayed.
This is my sample code:

```
$output = shell_exec('/root/bitcoinz/src/bitcoinz-cli -datadir=/root/bitcoinz/data  getnewaddress');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

$output1 = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output1</pre>";
```

First command doesn't work. It return empty string.
Second command works correctly. I can see list of directories and files in php

Comment: Most likely a user/permissions issue, since that first command is in the `/root` folder (I guess it belongs to user `root`?)

Comment: Yes, bitcoinz is in folder root, is installed by root user

Comment: How to add permission to call bitcoinz by the apache?